# Java Remove Specific Item From ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

Is using the remove() method okay? I've read an article that synchronization hasn't been added to the remove method. How do I properly remove a **specific** item from a ConcurrentHashMap?

Example Code:

```
    ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer> storage = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer>();
    storage.put("First", 1);
    storage.put("Second", 2);
    storage.put("Third",3);


    //Is this the proper way of removing a specific item from a tread-safe collection?
    storage.remove("First");

    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : storage.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        // ...
        System.out.println(key + " " + value);
    }
```

Comment: "I've read an article that synchronization hasn't been added to the remove method" Was that article written about the times of Java 5,6,7, or 8? Maybe it was written with an older Java version in mind.

Comment: Hopfully this link works http://javarevisited.blogspot.ca/2013/02/concurrenthashmap-in-java-example-tutorial-working.html. He says "Since update operations like put(), remove(), putAll() or clear() is not synchronized

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/02/concurrenthashmap-in-java-example-tutorial-working.html#ixzz3OM79B2ol
"

Comment: @peter.petrov - Calling the remove method on a ConcurrentHashMap like I did in my code example is okay, correct? thread-safety shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: Not fully sure. What this article means, I guess, is the following: in `remove` not the whole table is locked but only a given segment of it (as visible in the code posted by manouti). At least that's how I am reading the article and its meaning. So it all depends on your concurrency scenario. Not sure, need to research this myself from scratch if I am to answer it with certainty.

Comment: @peter.petrov - Hm, How then would I remove a specific item from a concurrecthashmap?

Comment: What you do is fine, I think. Read the source code. This Segment nested class in ConcurrentHashMap extends ReentrantLock, so it is a lock itself. Again, I doubt you will have such a concurrency scenario which would break the ConcurrentHashMap remove logic. But you should know better. :)

Comment: @peter.petrov - manouti confirmed it's fine.

Comment: Yeah, I would 99% guess so too.

Comment: There is no synchronization in a `ConcurrentHashMap`. It hasn't been 'added' to the `remove()` method or to any other method. There are *locks*, but no *synchronization*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `remove` method does synchronize on a lock. Indeed checking the code of `ConcurrentHashMap#remove()`, there is a call to a `lock` method that acquires the lock:

```
public V remove(Object key) {
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    return segmentFor(hash).remove(key, hash, null);
}
```

where `ConcurrentHashMap.Segment#remove(key, hash, null)` is defined as:

```
V remove(Object key, int hash, Object value) {
     lock();
     try {
        ...
```

Note the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) description:

> Retrieval operations (including `get`) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including `put` and `remove`). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently *completed* update operations holding upon their onset. For aggregate operations such as `putAll` and `clear`, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries. Similarly, Iterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do *not* throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time.

Comment: The remove method I used in my code example is okay then, right? I don't have to worry about thread-safety?

Comment: Yes it is fine. It is thread-safe in that no locking is needed to use it and no `ConcurrentModificationException` would occur.

Comment: @manouti- Thanks you rock, I've linked the article I got my information from. I think that author is incorrect then.

Comment: Again: the author just says that remove is not synchronized on the whole table object. That's how I am reading it at least.

Comment: @peter.petrov - So the author of the Blogspot post is incorrect?

Comment: No, I think he is correct but you shouldn't worry that much :)

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield I updated the answer with a Javadoc description. I guess that's what the author meant when he said "concurrent retrieval may not reflect most recent change on Map"

Comment: @peter.petrov - Just to confirm, and I'll let go of this situation, the way I called it on my example code above is fine, I don't have to worry about thread-safety?

Comment: Yes, your code is fine, and you don't have to worry. @manouti Good javadoc quote, I also think that's exactly what the article author meant. +1 from me.

Comment: Scroll down to the author's summary, #5: All operations of ConcurrentHashMap are thread-safe.

Comment: @spudone Yes, there's no contradiction in that. They are thread-safe, it's the level of consistency here which is being discussed (see the javadoc mahouti posted). So e.g. I guess in some convoluted scenario a `get` operation might see that something is in the table which is already `removed` from it :) That's how I am reading all this. Think about an analogue with RDBMS and isolation levels. Hope you see what I mean.

Comment: 'Synchronize on a lock' is a contradiction in terms. There is no synchronization in a `ConcurrentHashMap`, but there are locks, which are *locked* and *unlocked.*

Answer (score 4):

An **[Iterator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern)** should do the job:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> iterator = storage.entrySet().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = iterator.next();
    if(entry.getKey().equals("First"))
    {
       iterator.remove();
    }
 }
```

Reference: *https://dzone.com/articles/removing-entries-hashmap*

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly removeIf on the entrySet :

```
map.entrySet().removeIf( entry -> .. some condicion on entry )
```

Pay attention there is a **bug in Java 8** that is **only fixed from Java 9** ( [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8078645) ).